# Errors Launching GUI Launcher pycharm. "_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid"

Tags: python, parsing, tkinter, math, os.system

I am a new member of dealing with python, try to create a GUI launcher with facing some issues.

Would you have a look to my script and correct me.

my script as follow:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
root = Tk()
root.geometry("450x80")
root.title("GB Launcher")
root.configure(background="NavajoWhite3")
root.iconbitmap(r'Berkine2.ico')
#==============================================================
launcher = Frame(root)
launcher.grid()
#===============Menu_bar Configuration=========================================== def iExit(): iExit = tkinter.messagebox.askyesno("GB Launcher", "Do you want to exit") if iExit > 0: root.destroy() return
menu_bar = Menu(launcher)
System_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="System", menu=System_menu)
System_menu.add_command(label="Error Logger")
System_menu.add_command(label="System Resource Monitor")
System_menu.add_command(label="Terminal Window")
System_menu.add_separator()
System_menu.add_command(label="Exit", command=iExit)
help_menu = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=help_menu)
help_menu.add_command(label="About")
help_menu.add_command(label="Online Manual")
help_menu.add_command(label="Release Notes")
#==============LMK Menu Container===============================
lm = Menubutton(root, text="LMK")
lm.menu = Menu(lm)
lm["menu"] = lm.menu
lm.menu.add_command(label="OpenWorks", command=lambda: os.system("c:\Landmark\OpenWorks\OpenWorksExecution.bat"))
lm.menu.add_command(label="DSG", command=lambda: os.system("C:\Landmark\DSG10ep.5\DecisionSpace.exe"))
lm.menu.add_command(label="VNC", command=lambda: os.system('"C:\Program Files\RealVNC\VNC Viewer\vncviewer.exe"'))
lm.pack()
lm.grid_configure(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4)
#===============================================================
root.config(menu=menu_bar)
root.mainloop() 
#=================================================================
```

This error i face it

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Beginner1\venv\fsfs.py", line 50, in <module>
    lm.pack()
  File "C:\Users\m9b300\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2396, in pack_configure
    self.tk.call(
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside . which already has slaves managed by grid

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use (grid) and (pack) in tkinter at the same time.

Comment: First thank you for your prompt reply. Yes after I remove lm.pack() it's working fine. But i can't open another label until i close what is running first. unless the launcher not responding

Comment: This isn't correct. You can use both in a tkinter app, as long as you don't use both with widgets that have the same parent.